# Batch file opens in wrong place

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run a batch file (launch.bat in this case) from a different batch file (random.bat).

I wrote this in `random.bat`:

```
start \folder\launch.bat`
```

`launch.bat` uses other files that are located in the `\folder\`.

When I run `random.bat` it says that the files that `launch.bat` needs cannot be found in the folder that `random.bat` is located in.

I wanted to know how to run `launch.bat` from where it is, and not from where `random.bat` is located

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. Looking for private resources relative to the working directory is incorrect. Make launch.bat find its private resources relative to its own path (i.e. `%~dp0`).

Answer (score 0):

If you type `start /?` in your command prompt you get the informations you need or look [here at the technet description of start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx):

> `/d <Path>` Specifies the startup directory.

Your command should look like:

```cmd
start /D \folder \folder\launch.bat
```

as you pass the startup directory with `/D`.

Comment: Hi @Justin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of `launch.bat` just add the line:

```bat
@CD /D "%~dp0"
```

---

Also, if you are wishing to run a batch file from another your best bet is to use `Call` instead of `Start` in `random.bat`:

```bat
Call "folder\launch.bat"
```

If you don't have write access to launch.bat, then use the following in `random.bat`:

```bat
If Exist "folder\launch.bat" (
    PushD "folder"
    Call "launch.bat"
    PopD
)
```

Comment: If the `@CD /D "%~dp0"` approach is used, it will probably remain in that directory upon return to `random.bat`. Probably should use `PUSHD "%~dp0"` at the beginning and `POPD` before exiting `launch.bat`.

Comment: @lit, I don't disagree but if they can write to `launch.bat`, then I'd suggest they also post it's content such that we can restructure as part of a proper solution instead of guessing.